# Problemas ao resgatar dados de um arquivo json

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

Estou tentando carregar dados de um arquivo json em uma tabela html.

Estou tentando resgatar o json desta forma:

```
function getJson(){
    $.getJSON('dados/livros.json', function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

Exemplo do json que estou tentando resgatar:

```
{
"livros": [
        {
            "id":1,
            "imagem":"images/JavaScriptEJquery.jpg",
            "nome":"Javascript e Jquery - Desenvolvimento de Interfaces Web Interativas",
            "autor":"JON DUCKETT",
            "genero":"Didatico",
            "anoEdicao":"2016",
            "editora":"AltaBooks",
            "estado":"Disponivel"
        },
        {
            "id":2,      
            "imagem":"images/ScrumAArteDeFazerODobroNaMetadeDoTempo.jpg",
            "nome":"Scrum - A Arte de Fazer o Trabalho na Metade do Tempo",
            "autor":"JEFF SUTHERLAND",
            "genero":"Didatico",
            "anoEdicao":"2016",
            "editora":"LEYA",
            "estado":"Indisponivel"
        }
    ]
}
```

Localização do arquivo json:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Error:

> jquery-3.3.1.js:9600 Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'file:///D:/Catalogo%20de%20Livros/dados/livros.json' from origin
>   'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only
>   supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension,
>   https.

Já estou a algum tempo pesquisando mas ainda não consegui solucionar este problema, nunca tinha me deparado com este erro antes. Qual é a causa este error ? como resolver ?

Comment: Levi, acho que o seu problema é o mesmo que esse, dá uma olhada: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27742070/angularjs-error-cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-protocol-schemes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você tiver usando o Chrome, esse é um bug conhecido do próprio Chrome:

Link: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=40787&q=ajax%20local&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Pri%20Area%20Feature%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Modified%20Owner%20Mstone%20OS

Tente rodar no Firefox ou outro navegador, ou use um webserver, tipo http-server.

Link para um thread em inglês sobre isso: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533078/getjson-not-working-with-local-json-file

Answer (score 0):

Testei a sua função e funcionou normalmente Levi, porém fiz uma chamada AJAX para que possa testar

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: './dados/livros.json',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (jsonDadosRetorno) {
                console.log(jsonDadosRetorno);
            },
            error: function () {
            }
        });
```

Outra opção colocando o ./ no seu caminho relativo

```
$.getJSON('./dados/livros.json', function(data){
console.log(data);
```